# How to create a fade in effect on the selection?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

Regarding macros, there's very few done with Impress (no record of macros, no Python scripting, only Basic etc.), and very few samples.

There's no sample how to create "manually" a text animation. I've found one [here](https://gist.github.com/maffoo/977752?_pjax=%23gist-pjax-container) (6 years old) and there's a lot of information.

So far I've managed to (1) scan for a text animation "fadein" that is already there (2) scan for all other text animations, and then remove them an replace them by a clone of the "fadein" animation:

```
sub MyFunction
    ' --------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' (1) scan for a text animation "fadein" that is already there
    effectNodeFadeIn = Null
    doc = ThisComponent
    numSlides = doc.getDrawPages().getCount()
    slide = doc.drawPages(numSlides-1)

    mainSequence = getMainSequence(slide)    
    clickNodes = mainSequence.createEnumeration()
    while clickNodes.hasMoreElements() and IsNull(effectNodeFadeIn)
        clickNode = clickNodes.nextElement()

        groupNodes = clickNode.createEnumeration()
        while groupNodes.hasMoreElements() and IsNull(effectNodeFadeIn)
            groupNode = groupNodes.nextElement()

            effectNodes = groupNode.createEnumeration()
            while effectNodes.hasMoreElements() and IsNull(effectNodeFadeIn)
                effectNode = effectNodes.nextElement()
                ' ICIC

                if effectNode.ImplementationName = "animcore::ParallelTimeContainer" then
                    if hasUserDataKey(effectNode, "preset-id") then
                        v = getUserDataValue(effectNode, "preset-id")
                        if v = "ooo-entrance-fade-in" then ' ooo-entrance-appear
                            effectNodeFadeIn = effectNode
                        end if
                    end if
                end if
                ' useless loop just in case I need it:
                animNodes = effectNode.createEnumeration()
                while animNodes.hasMoreElements()
                    animNode = animNodes.nextElement()
                wend
            wend
        wend
    wend
    ' --------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' (2) scan for all other text animations, 
    ' and then remove them an replace them by a clone of the "fadein" animation
    if not IsNull(effectNodeFadeIn) then

        clickNodes = mainSequence.createEnumeration()
        while clickNodes.hasMoreElements()
            clickNode = clickNodes.nextElement()

            groupNodes = clickNode.createEnumeration()
            while groupNodes.hasMoreElements()
                groupNode = groupNodes.nextElement()

                effectNodes = groupNode.createEnumeration()
                while effectNodes.hasMoreElements()
                    effectNode = effectNodes.nextElement()
                    ' ICIC

                    if effectNode.ImplementationName = "animcore::ParallelTimeContainer" then
                        if hasUserDataKey(effectNode, "preset-id") then
                            v = getUserDataValue(effectNode, "preset-id")
                            if v <> "ooo-entrance-fade-in" then ' ooo-entrance-appear
                                groupNode.removeChild(effectNode)
                                n = effectNodeFadeIn.createClone()
                                groupNode.appendChild(n)

                                ' useless loop just in case I need it:
                                animNodes = effectNode.createEnumeration()
                                while animNodes.hasMoreElements()
                                    animNode = animNodes.nextElement()
                                wend
                            end if
                        end if

                    end if
                wend
            wend
        wend
    end if
end sub

function hasUserDataKey(node as Object, key as String) as Boolean
    for each data in node.UserData
        if data.Name = "node-type" then
            hasUserDataKey = True
            exit function
        end if
    next data
    hasUserDataKey = False
end function

function getUserDataValue(node as Object, key as String) as Variant
    for each data in node.UserData
        if data.Name = key then
            getUserDataValue = data.Value
            exit function
        end if
    next data
end function
```

When I clone the effect, it's still "linked" to the original text and then the parent is removed and replaced by the "fadein" text. Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: Where are the definitions of `hasUserDataKey()` and `getUserDataValue()`?

Comment: Question updated with the 2 missing functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have selected text inside of a shape, so use Basic code as follows:

```vb
Sub AddAnimation
    xTextCursor = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Selection(0)
    xText = xTextCursor.getText()
    xText.TextEffect = com.sun.star.presentation.AnimationEffect.FADE_FROM_BOTTOM
End Sub
```

Or in python:

```py
import uno
from com.sun.star.presentation.AnimationEffect import FADE_FROM_BOTTOM

def add_animation():
    oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    xTextCursor = oDoc.CurrentController.Selection.getByIndex(0)
    xText = xTextCursor.getText()
    xText.TextEffect = FADE_FROM_BOTTOM
```

For reasons not entirely clear to me, the result is Wipe rather than Fade In.

Documentation is at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Drawings/Animations_and_Interactions.  The `ShapeHelper` class from that page is defined in [ShapeHelper.java](http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/DevelopersGuide/Drawing/ShapeHelper.java).

Comment: And, thank you it's a good beginning I'll try to search for the good constant, but I need to change the duration to "one second", too... any idea?

Comment: I've modified my question with my 2 big loops, which is almost working.

Comment: I'm still searching for working source code... I found this where the codes is almost working, it's impressive : creation of text, creation of effects, everything seems ok, but the duration is ignored... I launch the macro, it generates everything except that the duration is ignored, but if I manually click on the "duration" of a text element, and change it manually then it works (it seems it removes and recreate another node with the good information in it...) I'm so close, it's very frustrating... http://hermione.s41.xrea.com/pukiwiki/pukiwiki.php?OOoBasic%2FImpress%2FAnimation

Comment: I check your answer as valid because you put me on the right track even though I've given up on this one...